# get only integer value from string

Tags: c#

I need to get only the last number from the string. The string contains pattern of string+integer+string+integer i.e. "GS190PA47". I need to get only 47 from the string.

Thank you

Comment: Google "regular expressions", and try this tool to experiment
http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: If you need only  47 , the easiest way is substring the last two character of your string :)

Comment: is the format fix? 2 string + 3 int + 2 string + 2 int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple regular expression chained to the end of the string for any number of integer digits

```
string test = "GS190PA47";
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+$");
var m = r.Match(test);

if(m.Success == false)
    Console.WriteLine("Ending digits not found");
else
    Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "GS190PA47";
var x = Int32.Parse(Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Last().Value);
```

If string always ends with number, you can simply use `\d+$` pattern, as Steve suggests.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this regex:

(\d+)(?!.*\d)

you can test it with this online tool: [link](http://www.rubular.com/r/pZsERUUUxZ)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is less or more efficient than RegEx (Profile it)

```
 string input = "GS190PA47";
 var x = Int32.Parse(new string(input.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
```

### Edit:

Amazingly it is actually much faster than regex

```
var a = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            string input = "GS190PA47";
            var x = Int32.Parse(new string(input.Reverse().TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).Reverse().ToArray()));
        }
        a.Stop();
        var b = a.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine(b);

        a = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            string input = "GS190PA47";
            var x = Int32.Parse(Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().Last().Value);
        }
        a.Stop();
         b = a.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Comment: Granted not quite what you were after but food for thought. Could use SkipWhile or Substring if the structure is deterministic.

Comment: This would get all numbers in the input (joined together), not just the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string input = "GS190PA47";

Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+\D+(\d+)");
int number = int.Parse(r.Match(input).Groups[1].Value);
```

Pattern means we find set of digits (190), next set of non-digit chars (PA) and finally sought-for number.

Don't forget include using System.Text.RegularExpressions directive.